# Unable to run Invissible Cloak python code on Google Collaboratory. Showing Error

Tags: python, runtime-error, google-colaboratory, invisible

I was trying to run this invisible cloak project on google colab, but it showed me this error. It's a guaranteed tried & tested Code.

```py
import cv2 
import numpy as np 
import time 


print(cv2.__version__) 

capture_video = cv2.VideoCapture("video.mp4") 

time.sleep(1) 
count = 0
background = 0


for i in range(60): 
    return_val, background = capture_video.read() 
    if return_val == False : 
        continue

background = np.flip(background, axis = 1) # flipping of the frame 

# we are reading from video 
while (capture_video.isOpened()): 
    return_val, img = capture_video.read() 
    if not return_val : 
        break
    count = count + 1
    img = np.flip(img, axis = 1) 

    # convert the image - BGR to HSV 
    # as we focused on detection of red color 


    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) 


    lower_red = np.array([100, 40, 40])
    upper_red = np.array([100, 255, 255]) 
    mask1 = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red) 

    lower_red = np.array([155, 40, 40]) 
    upper_red = np.array([180, 255, 255]) 
    mask2 = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red) 


    mask1 = mask1 + mask2 


    mask1 = cv2.morphologyEx(mask1, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, np.ones((3, 3), 
                                        np.uint8), iterations = 2) 
    mask1 = cv2.dilate(mask1, np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8), iterations = 1) 
    mask2 = cv2.bitwise_not(mask1) 


    res1 = cv2.bitwise_and(background, background, mask = mask1) 
    res2 = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = mask2) 
    final_output = cv2.addWeighted(res1, 1, res2, 1, 0) 

    cv2.imshow("INVISIBLE MAN", final_output) 
    k = cv2.waitKey(10) 
    if k == 27: 
        break
```

The error the code displays is shown here:
[image]

Can't use jupyter or any other software due to lack of Hardware Capabilities.

Comment: Include the error output in your code rather than an image.

Answer (score 1):

The error is self explanatory. Your resulting background image is empty (its actually `None`) as you do not seem to be having the `"video.mp4"`.
providing a video clip (i.e. video.mp4) should fix your issue.
To see this is the case, simply execute this example clip taken from [here](https://standaloneinstaller.com/blog/big-list-of-sample-videos-for-testers-124.html), in a cell prior to executing your code:

```
!wget -c http://mirrors.standaloneinstaller.com/video-sample/small.mp4 -O video.mp4
```